# Name of this Plant and how to keep it straight

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

What is the name of this plant and also how do i keep main trunk straight.

When i bought this plant 7 months ago its leaves were curly and damaged  as you can see some old leaves are still there , later i started feeding it 20-20-20 fertilizer 4 months ago and now new leaves are in good shape and plant looks healthy.

[image]
[image]

I took this cutting (shown in below image) from above mother plant and i put it in water and after month it started rooting and later i put it in well draining soil and now new leaves are growing from nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how to keep it straight.  Buy a  bamboo or coated metal stake.  Or use a stick from old window blinds.  Insert the stake in the soil to the bottom of the pot.  Gently tie the post to the plant.  You old leggings or buy plant ties.

Comment: Will do so, i have few bamboo sticks

Answer (score 0):

The growth looks like it is probably some sort of ficus... some grow fairly gnarly, some grow pretty straight, training it shouldn't be different than anything else, bind with sticks and twine or wire, and trim off growth that isn't where you want it.